# Wix Triggered Emails - Send to custom form submitter (not contact OR member)

Tags: velo

Firstly, my site does not have contacts or members or a sign up. It is simply used to register for an activity which then prompts the admin to create them an account in a 3rd party site that they do actually have login information for (this 3rd party site is embedded in my wix site)

I have a custom form in my wix site that is tied to a custom collection. Using automation, I as the admin am receiving an email about the information of the form submission (name, email, etc). The problem however, is that I cant find a way to send my triggered email to the email address of the site visitor that submitted the form.

The reasons for this that I cant seem to workaround are:

- custom forms dont allow you to send emails in automation, only receive
- the send triggered email code I've been able to find online so far only provides examples for sending a triggered email to a currently logged in member or a person thats in your contacts

  - this is done through a unique ID in the contacts table or members table from what I can tell,
    neither of which I have

I simply need to be able to send a triggered email to the email address of the site viewer who submitted a particular form

Is this possible, thanks!

I tried to play around with this snippet, setting variable names... but again this only works with adding the submitter to your contacts

```
import { triggeredEmails } from 'wix-crm';
import wixCRM from 'wix-crm';
import { session } from 'wix-storage';

$w.onReady(() => {
    $w("#dataset1").onReady(() => {
        $w("#dataset1").onAfterSave(() => {

            //TRIGGERED EMAIL  
            wixCRM.createContact({
                "firstName": $w('#firstName').value,
                "lastName": $w("#lastName").value,
                "emails": [$w("#email").value]

            }).then((contactId) => {

                triggeredEmails.emailContact(emailId, contactId, {
                    variables: {
                        firstName: session.getItem("firstName"),
                        lastName: session.getItem("lastName"),
                        email: session.getItem("email")

                    }
                });
            });
            //
        });
    });

    $w("#firstName, #lastName, #email").onInput(() => {

        session.setItem("firstName", $w("#firstName").value)
        session.setItem("lastName", $w("#lastName").value)
        session.setItem("email", $w("#email").value)

    })
});
```